# GKE usage metering stopped exporting data to BigQuery dataset

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm experiencing the following issue: we have GKE metering [export](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-usage-metering#enable-usage-metering) set up. It has worked for our clusters well, until March 31st, 2020, where GKE stopped sending any new data to the BigQuery datasets.

No changes have been done to the setup.

I tried to create a new dataset and point GKE to it in order to try to solve this, but even for a new dataset no data is sent.

Has something changed on the Google side end of March?
Is there a way to make GKE metering work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue by upgrading the master to 1.15.11-gke.9

The cluster is on regular channel, so on April 1st is was automatically upgraded to 1.15.9-gke.24 which broke the metering export functionality (which has been functional on 1.15.7-gke.2)